# How to use arguments with fopen?

Tags: c, arguments

I have to write a C program that uses arguments like this :

App.exe -in file.txt

I know something about argv and char *argc but..how do I use the argument with fopen?That i don't know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse argv to check if it's contains what you want.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("bad usage");
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-in") == 0)
    {
        char* filename = argv[2];
        FILE* f = fopen(filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: That equality comparison will never be true. You need to use `strcmp` instead.

Comment: And what's up with the `main` prototype?

Comment: Now it should be fine

Answer (score 2):

<sub>[Note that this doesn't answer the question, but it do show how to use arguments]</sub>

Learn about the arguments first, and how they are handled. Then you know how to use the arguments and pass a filename on to the `fopen` (or any other) function.

Try this little program first:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);

    for (size_t a = 0; i < argc; ++a)
    {
        printf("argv[%zu] = \"%s\"\n", a, argc[a]);
    }
}
```

If you execute this program like

```
args.exe -in file.txt
```

the output should be

```
argc = 3
argv[0] = "args.exe"
argv[1] = "-in"
argv[2] = "file.txt"
```